# Functional equations: $f(x^3) = \frac{1}{3}f(x)$ and $g(x/b) = b^{a}g(x)$ (uniqueness)

Tags: functional-equations, statistical-mechanics

Here are two functional equations, both of which come up in the theory of 2nd order phase transitions in statistical physics:
$$f(x^3) = \frac{1}{3}f(x)$$
and
$$g(x/b) = b^{a}g(x)\rm{,}$$
where $b$ is arbitrary positive real number and $a$ is a fixed real number.
For both of these it is pretty easy to write down a solution by "inspection". For the first
$$f(x)=\frac{C}{\log x}$$
works, while for the second
$$g(x)=\frac{D}{x^a}$$
works, where $C$ and $D$ are constants. But how would one prove that these are the only possible solutions (if indeed they are)?

Comment: We need more information to have the uniqueness you mentioned. There are several more solutions that are not of the given form.

Comment: For the second one, within reason one can write $g(x)=g\left(1\big /\frac 1x\right)=\left(\frac 1{x^a}\right)\times g(1)$, which defends the form you wrote.  For the first one, you probably want to add some continuity assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one, note that if there is a real number $a$ such that
$$g(\tfrac{x}{b})=b^ag(x),$$
for all $x,b\in\Bbb{R}$, then in particular for $x=1$ and $b=y^{-1}$ you have
$$g(y)=y^{-a}g(1),$$
so for the constand $D:=g(1)$ you indeed have
$$g(x)=\frac{D}{x^a},$$
for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.

For the first one, there are many more solutions, unless you assume $f$ to be continuous. As it stands, you can partition $\Bbb{R}$ into subsets of the form
$$P_x:=\{x^{3^n}:\ n\in\Bbb{Z}\}.$$
Then by the functional equation, given the value of $f(x)$ for some $x$, the value of $f(y)$ is determined for all $y\in P_x$. But the values on different sets are independent. For example,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\log(x)}&\text{ if } x=2^{3^n} \text{ for some }n\in\Bbb{Z}\\
0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$